# MySQL query with join operation translate to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I need to convert following mysql query to mongo. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
SELECT f.Datetime, c.Air Temperature(Celcius),f.Surface Temperature(Celcius) FROM firedata f JOIN climatedata c ON f.Date = c.Date where f.Confidence > 80 and f.Confidence < 100;
```

Comment: can you show the schemas of the tables?

Comment: Simply asking for direct SQL translations is not really valid for a question here. The two types of database engine are wildly different, and as such you "should" in fact be altering the structure instead of attempting to use MongoDB *"Just like I did with my SQL database"*. They're simply not the same so the code does not correlate. Instead, show the data you have and the expected query pattern in which you need to use that data along with the result you expect to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB the joined data will either be nested inside single documents (on which case you won't need the join) or will be in different ones and your best bet will be the aggregation framework, specifically the "lookup" pipeline stage.

Without knowing more details about either implementation, it will be something like:

```
fireDataCollection.aggregate([
    { 
       $match: {
          $and: [
            { "Confidence": { $gt: 80 } },
            { "Confidence": { $lt: 100 } }
          ]
       }           
    },
    {
       $lookup: {
          from: "climateDataCollection",
          localField: "Date",
          foreignField: "Date",
          as: "Climate"
       }
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$Climate"
    }
])
```

The $unwind step is optional and will turn the "Climate" field (which after the lookup will be a collection of every Climate matching the date from the firedata) into multiple documents each containing only one nested document of "Climate"